# How to pass the key version when creating key ( Symmetric/ Asymmetric) in GCP KMS

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-kms

When creating a key in GCP KMS through GCP Console , we can enter the key version. Ex. 1, 2, .. v20 etc.

---

When programmatically creating a key in Java , I am unable to find how to pass the key version of my choice.

[Create Asymmetric Key in GCP KMS doc](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/create-key#create-asymmetric)

```java
public void createKeyAsymmetricDecrypt(
      String projectId, String locationId, String keyRingId, String id) throws IOException {
    // Initialize client that will be used to send requests. This client only
    // needs to be created once, and can be reused for multiple requests. After
    // completing all of your requests, call the "close" method on the client to
    // safely clean up any remaining background resources.
    try (KeyManagementServiceClient client = KeyManagementServiceClient.create()) {
      // Build the parent name from the project, location, and key ring.
      KeyRingName keyRingName = KeyRingName.of(projectId, locationId, keyRingId);

      // Build the asymmetric key to create.
      CryptoKey key =
          CryptoKey.newBuilder()
              .setPurpose(CryptoKeyPurpose.ASYMMETRIC_DECRYPT)
              .setVersionTemplate(
                  CryptoKeyVersionTemplate.newBuilder()
                      .setAlgorithm(CryptoKeyVersionAlgorithm.RSA_DECRYPT_OAEP_2048_SHA256))

              // Optional: customize how long key versions should be kept before destroying.
              .setDestroyScheduledDuration(Duration.newBuilder().setSeconds(24 * 60 * 60))
              .build();

      // Create the key.
      CryptoKey createdKey = client.createCryptoKey(keyRingName, id, key);
      System.out.printf("Created asymmetric key %s%n", createdKey.getName());
    }
  }
```

---

So, can we pass the key version of our choice , when creating key in KMS through above code?

I think , there are some parameters that we can pass when creating the key through GCP terminal but I am not sure. I am interested in knowing how to pass version info when creating key in java.

Comment: When creating keys programmatically using the Google Cloud KMS API or client libraries, you typically don't explicitly specify a key version. Instead, you create a key, and the service automatically manages the versions for you. If you want to manage key versions explicitly, you can rotate keys. Key rotation creates a new version of the key, and you can manage the rotation schedule according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have custom version in KMS. When you create a key, the version is 1. The next version will increment this value, and so forth.